# Godot raycasts add exception to parent node but still allow children

Tags: godot, raycasting, gdscript

I have an object with an outer shell surrounding an interior object. Both are collision objects. I want to ray cast onto this object and only detect the interior object (the cast should ignore the outer shell). I understand I can move these objects onto different collision layers, but I need them to have the same collision layers.

I've tried to use exceptions on the ray cast object to ignore the outer shell object, but the interior object (which is a child of the outer shell) is also ignored.

How can I get the ray cast to ignore this outer shell object while still colliding with its children?

Comment: They are different bodies, right? What inconvenience is there in making the interior object not a child of the outer shell?

Comment: They're different bodies, but they need to move together like one object. The outer shell is a RigidBody and I want the interior object (which is an Area2D) to follow the position of the RigidBody

Comment: Well, you could tell the raycast to only collide with areas, does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it needs to also detect other bodies. I’ve resigned to just reworking my collision layer setup to allow my outer shell to be ignored. Thanks for the suggestions 